# Automatically stretching elements to fit in parent container using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a vertical navigation bar inside a box with fixed height. How can I make the buttons dynamically change height equally to fit inside the box? Here's a jsfiddle to demonstrate what I mean.

http://jsfiddle.net/0w3f2fm1/

So now if I am to add a sixth or a seventh button, they will be evenly stretched to fit `nav` container. Is it possible to make it with css only, or should javascript/jquery intervene?

Note: They will be added using back-end php/mysql application, not by code.

Also note, that the height I currently have is done using padding because I want the text to be centered inside the button.

Thanks

Comment: You want to the navigation buttons fill the height from the parent box? (the main box, which wraps the navigation?)

Comment: Yeah. Making the buttons all evenly fill the parent box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in you question is you have given parent height in fixed size and you want child elements to be stretched to fill the parent.

- So you have to give the height of li in percentages.
- about vertical centering of text you can use either display:table-cell, vertical-align:middle properties however using tables for layout is not a best practice.
- So Im using positions to center align the text.

Here is the jsbin:

http://jsbin.com/jirozicifedo/2/

Here is the dynamic solution (Javascript):

http://jsbin.com/batuyoxupofu/1/edit

Comment: This works, but it's not dynamic. What if a new button was put in? I don't wanna keep changing css each time I want a new button. Is there another way to do this? `height: auto;` doesn't work, so maybe javascript?

Comment: I wish you've seen the comments in jsbin css. Basic formula is divide the no.of li elements and give the percentage as li height. Otherwise use flexbox as mentioned by @Francky_V

Comment: I did see them, but still this method will have me editing the css everytime a button is added. Can this be done using javascript?

Comment: I've heard that using javascript for styling is not a best practice however we can solve it with javascript.

Comment: @TarekDeeb I've updated the Javascript solution but its not recommended to use Javascript for structuring page.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use html + css instead of javascript.

And since the new function of SO isn't working yet, link here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pHhEo

Code here:

```
<style>
    table {
        width: 200px;
        height: 400px;
    }
    table tr {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    table tr td {
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
    table tr td:hover {
        background-color: #000;
        color: #fff;
        cursor: default;
    }
</style>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Button 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Button 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Button 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Button 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Button 5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you change the height, the button's height will also change automatically.

Comment: No way to keep using ul>li>a instead of tables?

Comment: You can. But this time I guess Javascript is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Flex-box to achieve the basic idea of what you are describing:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

It's super-easy to center things (both direction) and it's really, well, flexible and also it has a ton of option as to how to distribute content.

The only draw-back is that it isn't great for compatibility with older browser. It's fairly well-supported for newer ones though (it is a strong canditate to be added as a standard), depends what exactly it is going to be used for....

Fast to learn too.

===========EDIT, see comments========

```
html:

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="item">Button1</div>
            <div class="item">Button2</div>
            <div class="item">Button3</div>
            <div class="item">Button4</div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

For CSS:

```
body {
    height: 30em;
    border: 2px solid #ff00ff;
}

.container {
    height:100%;
    width: 10em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content:center;

}

.item {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

Borders just to show extent of the blocks, if you want to try it in a browser. I checked and seems all new browser (including IE) support this.

Oh, and other thing you might decide you want after all: They don't have to be of equal size, you can easily set proportions for them.

If you id="itemX" for each button, you can use the following to set any ratios you want:

```
#item1 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#item2 {
  flex-grow: 2;
}

#item3 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

So in that case, #item2 will use 2/4 of the available container (so in this case, the full height of the container), and the other ones 1/4 each...

Comment: Interesting! This is the first I've heard of Flex. However, it doesn't resize the elements, it just places evenly spaced gaps between them. Not that efficient if there are many items inside the box with fixed height.

Comment: You can use flex-grow & flex-shrink on your child elements and it will resize them... Good point for efficiency I have to admit I'm doing small-scale stuff with it so it isn't critical...Although from another perspective, if you're going to use flexblox, you might as well make your design responsive (that's what it is for: to make responsive design easier to achieve).

Comment: It would still leave gaps between the buttons.

Comment: Interesting discussion. I don't have a whole lot of experience in this (and that might just be why I picked up flexbox more readily, not really having yet my own design paradigms). But not, it will not, see edit of my answer for example.

Comment: For some reason it didn't work for my code, but works for yours. jsfiddle.net/0w3f2fm1/1 Here's the edits to the original code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot to declare your flex container (<ul>). You need display: flex (or inline-flex)

Comment: I find it weird that you start out by saying you prefer a solution in pure CSS/HTML and not having to edit the CSS.... WHich is precisely what I am giving your here, yet you accept a solution which:

1 - Require java
2 - Uses the java to edit the css